# How to make fontconfig fallback work?

Tags: terminal, fonts, gnome-terminal, fontconfig

I'm trying to use powerline fonts, but most of the powerline fonts don't look too good in my terminal. Instead I'd like to use a regular non-Powerline font, and specify a fallback Powerline font for those special characters that aren't defined in the first font.

How can I do this using fontconfig files? And then how would I define it in my application? Right now I'm using the name of the font like `Droid Sans Mono for Powerline 10`, but if I've set up a fallback then would I be specifying a generic name like `monospace` here instead?